# Inconsistent behavior of document.write in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

#### Problem

While executing multiple document.write, I notice that they dont modify the DOM immediately. The first document.write executes immediately, while the impact of others on the DOM is only visible at the end of that `<script>` block. In Chrome when I tested, it gives the results below. However in Firefox, the result is the same as Chrome if I just let this code run but different (see below) when I step through the code one statement at a time. Could someone explain this behavior?

#### Code

```
<script>  
    document.write("<script src='test.js'>" + "</" + "script>");  
    console.log(document.scripts.length);  
    document.write("<script src='test2.js'>" + "</" + "script>");  
    console.log(document.scripts.length);  
    document.write("<script src='test3.js'>" + "</" + "script>");  
    console.log(document.scripts.length);
</script>
```

#### Chrome(v.41) Log

```
2
2
2
```

#### Firefox(v.36) Log (When stepping through the code in Dev Tools)

```
2
3
4
```

#### Update

Original number of scripts in the DOM was 1 (the inline script written above). Chrome updated the DOM after first document.write but waited after that. Is that considered buggy behavior?

Comment: Chrome didn't parse the DOM yet.

Comment: Hi, Slaks. I understand that. But it does parse the DOM after the first document.write is executed to update the number of scripts to 2 but then stops subsequently. Is that considered buggy?

Comment: Does it cause bugs in your code?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to build a scanner of sorts for JS scripts injected on a page dynamically via document.write, but with this I get inconsistent results.

Comment: Lets try to solve that problem then, rather than trying to come to a consensus on whether or not a browser behavior that we can't change is buggy..

Comment: It's mainly because, the browser couldn't parse the script `test2.js` by the time it executes the next statement. That's why you see the counter is same.

But when you debug, the browser would execute the statements sequentially and would fetch the file when you have breakpoint in the counter statements.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations everyone. @KevinB I basically want to know if a document.write wrote a script tag on the page, if it did then extract its src.

Comment: Am I missing something or do you have a typo in your code? Shouldn't document.write("<script src='test.js'" + "</" + "script>");  be document.write("<script src='test.js'>" + "</" + "script>");  ?
By not closing the first tag, different browsers might come up with a different solution solving the DOM tree.

Comment: Sorry thats a typo. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome behavior in the question exactly matches the [4.01 specification's model:](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.4)

> 18.2.4 Dynamic modification of documents
>
> Scripts that are executed when a document is loaded may be able to modify the document's contents dynamically. The ability to do so depends on the scripting language itself (e.g., the **"document.write"** statement in the HTML object model supported by some vendors).
>   The dynamic modification of a document may be modeled as follows:
>
> **1.** All SCRIPT elements are evaluated in order as the document is loaded.
>
> **2.** **All** script constructs within a given SCRIPT element that generate SGML CDATA are evaluated. Their **combined generated text** is inserted in the document in place of the SCRIPT element.
>
> **3.** The **generated CDATA is re-evaluated**.

*(bold emphasis is mine)

Chrome and firefox may be performing look-ahead running through (2)<=>(3) on well formed **uncombined generated text**, but they are supposed to act as if they have not evaluated them according to the specification's model.

Consequently, **Chrome's reporting the same number of scripts in the document until the parent script terminates is not "buggy"**. (You should assume everything you add in this fashion will be added/evaluated as if it precedes the next script element in the page and nothing more.)

Because HTML5 is being **incrementally deployed**, HTML 4.01 behavior should be correct and expected by a document and it can't count on any clarifications in HTML5, whether it specifies an HTML5 DOCTYPE or not. As such there is little reason to look at the HTML5 specification when defending a behavior that is defined in 4.01. **Every document must be compatible with 4.01 for any features that existed in 4.01 until there is a new DOCTYPE that indicates incompatibility instead of requests new features if available.**

Comment: I do not think this explains the current behaviour. Chrome still outputs the value of document.scripts.length as 4 after this script has finished executing. 
Plus, your other comments about the inefficiency of document.write and how to monkey-patch it has no relevance to the question asked.

Comment: couple of questions - Any reason why you have pointed the HTML4 spec and not the HTML5 one? "Their combined generated text is inserted in the document in place of the SCRIPT element." -- I do not see the generated text being replaced, it is appended after the script element. Chrome seems to be following part of this behaviour then?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find official documentation about that, but making some tests I noticed that browser append those scripts to document once the response from script's source url is taken (except for the first)

```js
document.write("<script src='a.js'>" + "</" + "script>");  
console.log(document.scripts.length);
document.write("<script src='b.js'>" + "</" + "script>");  
console.log(document.scripts.length);
document.write("<script src='c.js'>" + "</" + "script>");
console.log(document.scripts.length);

document.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if (document.readyState == "complete") {
  console.log('Complete: '+document.scripts.length+' scripts found')
 }
}
```

From Chrome console you should see something like this
[image]

But it loads scripts instantly if they don't have source

```js
document.write("<script>" + "</" + "script>");  
console.log(document.scripts.length);
document.write("<script>" + "</" + "script>");  
console.log(document.scripts.length);
document.write("<script>" + "</" + "script>");
console.log(document.scripts.length);
```

Moreover I also noticed that if just one `<script>` has source defined, following scripts (even without source) will not be appended to document until response is taken

```js
document.write("<script>" + "</" + "script>");  
console.log(document.scripts.length);
document.write("<script src='a.js'>" + "</" + "script>");  
console.log(document.scripts.length);
document.write("<script>" + "</" + "script>");
console.log(document.scripts.length);
```

However adding [async](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp) to `<script>` will solve the issue

```js
document.write("<script src='a.js' async>" + "</" + "script>");  
console.log(document.scripts.length);
document.write("<script src='b.js' async>" + "</" + "script>");  
console.log(document.scripts.length);
document.write("<script src='c.js' async>" + "</" + "script>");
console.log(document.scripts.length);

document.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if (document.readyState == "complete") {
  console.log('Complete: '+document.scripts.length+' scripts found')
 }
}
```

Comment: This is very interesting. However, it would be great if someone could tell me where the behaviour of this is documented. I couldn't find anything in the specs either.

Comment: Me too. However you can achieve that by adding `async` attr to script. I edited my post to show you..